# Invalid JSON primitive: 

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have a page which contains a user control say UserControl1 this User control contains another user control say UserControl2 and also this User control contains another user control UserControl3 .I nned to display a modal pop up on click of button (Server side)

I am able to get the pop up which is also another user control . Problem here is when i click on any of the button in the popped up window I get this error "Invalid JSON primitive: . ".

Any way to go about this ?

Thanks,
Francis

Comment: Difficult to say without being able to see the JSON output.

Comment: ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: .]
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject() +541762
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) +242
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) +51
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) +37

Comment: I am sorry do you mean this as the output ?

Comment: I was referring to the JSON itself; sorry if that wasn't clear. Some JSON string is being passed between the client and the server, and it is invalid. I can't tell you exactly *why* it's invalid if I can't see it.

Comment: ok thanks. Any suggestions as to any way i could find out how to get ths to working ?

Comment: Posting the invalid JSON string would be a good start. I'm sure you can dump it to a log or something from your server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, the control I was using to call the modalPopupExtender.Show() was inside an updatepanel, and it got conflicted, I just stopped using an updatepanel from my main form and it worked.
Hope this helps.